# Coldfusion Arrays and Session shopping cart

Tags: arrays, coldfusion, dreamweaver

I'm a noob with Coldfusion and I've been trying to figure out this simple issue for weeks now.  I have a shopping cart i've created using coldfusion and dreamweaver. I'm trying to figure out what I've got wrong in my Application.CFC that's not deleting the session on browser close or reload.. Any guidence would be greatly appreciated. TIA

**APPLICATION.CFC Code:** **Edited 4/19/2016 @ 10:55pm**

```
<cfcomponent> 
<cfset this.name = "cart"> 
<cfset application.datasource.name = "mmd24_shoppingcart">
<cfset application.directory.root.path = "productlist.cfm" > 
<cfset This.Sessionmanagement=True>
<cfset This.Sessiontimeout="#createtimespan(0,5,0,0)#">
<cfset This.applicationtimeout="#createtimespan(5,0,0,0)#">

<cfif isdefined("cookie.CFID") and isdefined("cookie.CFTOKEN")>
<cfset tempCFID = cookie.CFID >
<cfset tempCFTOKEN = cookie.cftoken >
<cfcookie name="CFID"  value="#tempCFID#" >
<cfcookie name="CFTOKEN"  value="#tempCFTOKEN#" >
</cfif> 
</cfcomponent>
```

**shoppingcart.cfm** **EDITED 4/19/2016 @ 10:55pm CST**

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<html>
<html lang="en">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width. initial-scale=1 
charset=utf-8>

<cfparam name = "url.productid" default = "">
<cfparam name = "url.qty" default = "">

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap
/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap
/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3
/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6
/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style> 
p.solid{border-style: solid;}
text.solid{border-style: solid;}
text.inset {border-style: inset;}
text.double {border-style: double;}
</style>
</head>

<body>

 <br />
 <center><h1><p> ShoppingCart</p></h1></center>
<cfquery name = "getlist" datasource="mmd24_shoppingcart">
              SELECT * 
              FROM Products
              Where Products.productID = <cfqueryparam  
              cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#url.productid#">
</cfquery>

<cflock scope="session" timeout="10">   

        <cfset addNew = true>

        <cfif not isDefined("session.cart")>

        <cfset session.cart = arrayNew(1)>

        <cfelse>

        <cfloop index="i" from="1" to="#arrayLen(session.cart)#">

            <cfif URL.productid is session.cart[i].productId>

            <cfset session.cart[i].productQty = 
             session.cart[i].productQty + 1>

         <cfset addNew = false>
                       </cfif>
                   </cfloop>

                </cfif>

                <cfif addNew is true>

                   <cfset newItem=StructNew()>

                   <cfset newItem.productId = URL.productid>

                   <cfset newItem.productName = getlist.ProductName>

                   <cfset newItem.productPrice = getlist.ProductPrice>

                   <cfset newItem.productDescription = 
                    getlist.ProductDescription>

                   <cfset newItem.productQty = URL.qty>

                   <cfset newItem.productPhoto = getlist.ProductPhoto>

                   <cfset ArrayAppend(session.cart, newItem)>

                </cfif>        

    <cfset TotalOrderAmount = 0>
    <cfset TotalItemAmount = 0>
    <cfset TotalTax = 0>
    <cfset counterhi = 0>
</cflock>

<cfoutput query ="getlist">


<cflock scope="session" type="readonly" timeout="10">

    <cfloop index="i" from="1" to="#arrayLen(session.cart)#">

<table class = "table table-bordered">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Product Photo</th>
        <th>Product Name</th>
        <th>Product Description</th>
        <th>Quantity Ordered</th>
        <th>Product Price</th>
      </th>
</thead>

<tr>
    <td><img src="#session.cart[i].ProductPhoto#"></td>
    <td>#session.cart[i].ProductName#</td>
    <td>#session.cart[i].ProductDescription#</td>
    <td>#session.cart[i].ProductQty#</td>
    <td>#DollarFormat(session.cart[i].ProductPrice)#</td>

    <cfset Itemtotal = #getlist.productprice# * 
     #session.cart[i].ProductQty#>
    <cfset OrderTotal = #Itemtotal#>
    <cfset Tax = #OrderTotal# * "0.07">
    <cfset TotalOrderAmount = #OrderTotal# + #Tax# + #TotalOrderAmount#>
    <cfset TotalItemAmount = #Itemtotal# + #TotalItemAmount#>
    <cfset TotalTax = #Tax# + #TotalTax#>
    <tr>
    <td> <b><text class=double>Item Total:</text></b><text 
    class=double>#DollarFormat(Itemtotal)# </text><br />
    <b><text class=double>Sales Tax:</text></b><text 
    class=double>#DollarFormat(Tax)# </text><br />
    </td>
    </table>

</cfloop>
</cflock>
</cfoutput> 

        <cfoutput query ="getlist">
    <br /> <br /> <br />
    <b><text class=double>Total Item Amount:</text></b><text 
    class=double> #DollarFormat(TotalItemAmount)# </text><br/>
    <b><text class=double>Total Tax Amount:</text></b><text 
    class=double> #DollarFormat(TotalTax)# </text><br/>
    <b><text class=double>Total Order Amount:</text></b><text 
    class=double> #DollarFormat(TotalOrderAmount)# </text><br/>
    <br /><br />
    <form action="customerform.cfm" method="post">
    <a input type="submit" name="submit" href="customerform.cfm" 
    class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Proceed to Checkout</a>
    <br>
    </br>
    <a input type="submit" name="submit" href="productlist.cfm" 
    class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Continue Shopping</a>
    <br />
</cfoutput> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try to understand how scopes work in ColdFusion, maybe you'll want to begin with the URL and FORM scopes. At the top of your shoppingcart.cfm you can for example dump the URL scope and see what is in it. <cfdump var="#URL#" /><cfabort> If ProductPrice is not in the URL you'll get an error when you'll try to use it in your code.

Comment: (Edit) Skimming the code it looks like you may be mixing concepts ie anchor versus input. `<a input type="submit" >`. May want to take a step back and start simply. Learn about how to pass values via method GET and POST and the difference between the various scopes in CF, ie FORM and URL scopes.

Comment: You might want to send this through http://validator.w3.org/ . A lot of the html is ... ummmm ... creative.

Comment: What is the actual issue you are experiencing? The question has changed several times, so it is no longer clear. BTW, if you are new to Stack Overflow, this question is a bit [too broad](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) as written and is likely to be closed. When posting, try and put together a  [*Minimal*, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). (Leave out anything not relevant to the problem, like css, etcetera and be sure to include any error messages.)  That helps both you and others to more easily identify the problem.

Answer (score 4):

FWIW, you should NEVER be referring to user input (the `URL` or `FORM` scope) for price and other information. You should take the ID of the product and look up the info from your database in order to store it in `session`. At best, the product ID and quantity are all you want to pull from user input, making sure that you have set a correctly typed `cfparam` for each.

Comment: (Edit) @WTFVet79 - Since you mentioned being new to CF (and possibly web development in general)... the reason you should never do it is because it allows users to potentially hack the form and set whatever price *they* want, such as $0. Golden rule: Never trust client supplied information.

Comment: true, this is just an assignment for class to where the teacher didn't really supply any type of material...basically says: "this is what your assignment is and if you can't figure it out (because she didn't "teach it") then "google" it..."    its driving me nuts!!!  I have done alot of editing and will repost up top and note the code is edited.  I appreciate everyone's help on this!!

Answer (score 1):

Specifically to the error, that is probably coming from this line:

```
<cfset sItem.price = url.ProductPrice>
```

Since you do not set a default value for url.ProductPrice using a cfparam, if you don't pass ProductPrice in to via URL each time, then it won't find it.  Perhaps you need to use a cfparam for each possible url var.

Comment: ah, ok. i will give it a try. thanks for the advice!!  is my array correct?